# Chamar rota de um botão não está funcionando

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-6

Preciso, quando eu criar um Operador, após ter criado, deveria chamar outra tela, a lista de operadores. Acontece que não está funcionando. A rota se chama **operator** e como eu coloco nesse botão?

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Criar</button>
```

Já tentei assim:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a routerLink="/operator"></a>Criar</button>
```

e assim

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/operator">Criar</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma correta é essa:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a routerLink="/operator">Criar</a></button>
```

Comment: Troquei a terminação da tag </a>. O problema é que o value do botão(Criar) ficou com link e consequentemente o texto ficou quase que invisível.